# Trouble Allocating Memory in Bash Script

Tags: bash, text, memory-management, scripting, fork

I tried to automate the process of cleaning up various wordlists I am working with. This is the following code for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Removes spaces and duplicates in a wordlist


echo "Please be in the same directory as wordlist!"
read -p "Enter Worldlist: " WORDLIST
RESULT=$( awk '{print length, $0}' $WORDLIST | sort -n | cut -d " " -f2- )
awk '!(count[$0]++)' $RESULT > better-$RESULT
```

This is the error I recieve after running the program:

```
./wordlist-cleaner.sh: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

First post, I hope I formatted it correctly.

Comment: Can you run any command at all? It looks like you've run out of memory.

Comment: Yes I can run commands with no problem.

Comment: $RESULT is no file.

Comment: so use `set -x` to see each command execute with all env variables expanded. Try your script on another machine or reboot and open only a terminal window, do you get the same result? pluse-uno for better than average first Q. Good luck.

Comment: Okay I will try running it on another computer, and figure out the set -x command. It runs for about 2 minutes before giving me that error. In response to Cyrus's question am I not redirecting the output right to the RESULT variable, do I need to pipe it again? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. For example, add 10 lines from the file WORDLIST and the desired output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe your intentions or desired output, but I guess this may do what you want

```
awk '{print length, $0}' "$WORDLIST" | sort -n | cut -d " " -f2- | uniq > better-RESULT
```

Notice that it's `better-RESULT` instead of `better-$RESULT` as you don't want that as a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah okay I got it to run successfully. I was trying to clean up wordlists I was downloading of the net. I have some knowledge of the basic variable usage in Bash, but not enough of the text manipulation commands like sed or awk. Thanks for the support.